# Are there integer solutions to $9^x - 8^y = 1$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

This came up in proving non-regularity of a certain language (powers of 2 over the ternary alphabet). Any clue to the above equation could help me move forward.

Edit:
Of course, $x = 1, y = 1$ is a solution. I am looking for non-trivial solutions.

Comment: yes x=1,y=1 is a soution

Comment: @avinash: out of curiosity, how does this come up in proving non-regularity of the language you describe?  The approach which first occurs to me is totally different.  Are you using the pumping lemma?

Comment: @Qiaochu: Yes, I was trying pumping lemma. But it's going nowhere. How did you solve it?

Comment: @avinash: the approach I thought of is unnecessarily complicated.  There is a theorem of Berstel which implies that if the language you're looking at is regular, then the number L_n of words of length n must be eventually periodic, and I believe one derives a contradiction from here.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Since I was getting nowhere near the solution, I have posted it as a separate question at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2083/ .

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Except $x=1$ and $y=1$ there aren't any.

We have that

$$3^{2x} - 1 = 8^y$$

i.e

$$ (3^x + 1)(3^x - 1)  = 8^y$$

Thus we must have that

$$3^x + 1 = 2^m, 3^x - 1 = 2^n$$

Thus $$2^m - 2^n = 2$$

i.e
$$ 2^n(2^{m-n} - 1) = 2$$

Thus $n=1$ and $m=2$.

Comment: You didn't use the assumption that x>1; you got n=1 which implies x=1. :-) (Many times a proof by contradiction can be simplified if you try to rewrite it without the contradication… it's usually worth a shot to see if it gets simpler.)

Comment: @Shree: Right, I will just delete that line.

Comment: @Moron, pardon my ignorance, but can you explain why it must be true that $3^x+1=2^m$ and $3^x-1=2^n$?

Comment: @user: If A*B = a power of 2 = 2^y, then, both must be powers of 2. (I am counting 1 to be a power of 2 = 2^0). This is because any prime that divides A, must divide 2^y and hence must be 2.

Comment: @Aryabhata Does this proof assume that $x,y\geq0$?

Comment: @Servaes: Yes. The case when at least one of them is $\lt 0$ is trivial and uninteresting.

Answer (score 17):

The only solution is $x=y=1$. This is a special case of [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) which was proven by Mihailescu in 2002: the only solution in natural numbers of $x^a - y^b = 1$ with $a,b\gt 1$ is $x=3$, $a=2$, $y=2$, and $b=3$.

But as Moron points out, it can be deduced much more elementarily.

Answer (score 7):

Equation $\rm\ 3^{2x}-2^{3y}=1\ $ is an instance of various special cases of [Catalan's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalans_conjecture).

First,$\ $ making the specialization $\rm\ \ \: z,\:p^n = 3^x,2^{3y}\ $ below yields $\rm\ x = 1 = y\ $ as desired.

**LEMMA**$\ \ $ $\rm z^2 - p^n = 1\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ z,\:p^n = \:3\ ,\:2^3\ $  or $\ 2,\:3\ $ for $\rm\ \ z,\:p\:,n\in \mathbb N,\ \ p\: $ prime

**Proof** $\rm\ \ \ (z+1)\:(z-1)\: =\: p^n\ \  \Rightarrow\ \ z+1 = p^{\:j},\ \ z-1 = p^k\ $ for some $\rm\ j,\:k\in \mathbb N$

$\rm\quad \:\Rightarrow\ \ \ \ 2\ =\ p^{\:j} - p^k\ =\ p^k\: (p^{\:j-k}-1) \ \Rightarrow\ p^k=2\ $ or $\rm\ p^k = 1 \ \Rightarrow\ \ldots$

Second, it's simply the special case $\rm\: X = 3^x,\ Y = 2^y\: $ of $\rm\ X^2 - Y^3 = 1\:,\: $ solved by Euler in 1738. Nowadays one can present this solution quite easily using elementary properties of $\rm\ \mathbb Z[\sqrt\[3\]{2}]\:$, e.g see p.44 of Metsankyla: [Catalan's Conjecture: another old diophantine problem solved](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2004-41-01/S0273-0979-03-00993-5/S0273-0979-03-00993-5.pdf). See also [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39561/is-there-an-elementary-way-to-find-the-integer-solutions-to-x2-y31) and [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25674/integer-points-of-an-elliptic-curve) and Schoof: [Catalan's Conjecture](http://www.maths.mq.edu.au/~alf/Humid%20Summer/catalan.pdf). Note also that Catalan equations are a special case of the theory of generalized Fermat (FLT) equations, e.g. see [Darmon's exposition](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/~darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/09.Ribenboim/paper.pdf).